# Best things to do in NY, when you're not that into cities?

Tags: new-york-city, nature-and-wildlife, outdoor-activities

I am heading to Chattanooga (Tennessee) in October- flying from London to JFK, and then flying on from there. I will have a few days in NY before heading on to Chattanooga, and am looking for recommendations for what to do with the time I have there.

I will probably do a couple of the 'must do' things (Empire State building & Statue of Liberty... maybe one or two others), but generally speaking, I'm not really interested in cities. I'm much more interested in nature & the outdoors- so Central Park is an obvious one of the 'must do' list that I will head for.

What are the other more outdoors/ nature based things that people would recommend I should try to see/ do while I'm in NY?

Comment: Plenty of suggestions for day-trips here:
https://www.timeout.com/newyork/travel/day-trips-from-nyc-to-beaches-parks-wineries-and-more

Comment: Thanks for the link- will definitely look into some of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a walk along the High Line. It’s a former elevated freight railway line that has been converted into a walkway or linear park.
https://www.thehighline.org/

You might find some other interesting things to do nearby.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions- I'll definitely look into it.